# Export Gridview to xlsx format

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview

I have problems for export the gridview content to a excel file (xlsx extension).
I can export it like xls extension, but not xlsx.
My code is:

```
#region === EXPORT GRID A EXCEL ===

protected void imgBtn_Consol_Export_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Lotes.xls");

    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xlsx";


    System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    gvwLotConsol_Plant.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

    //style to format numbers to string
    string style = @"<style> TD { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>"; //para formato texto
    Response.Write(style);

    Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
    Response.End();

}

public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(System.Web.UI.Control control)
{/* Verifies that the control is rendered */}

#endregion
```

I tried using xls extension but does not work, I tried with:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
```

It does not work, If anybody please can help me, that would be great.

Best regards!!!

Comment: "does not work" is not a useful description of your problem. Exporting data as HTML and sending an Excel header has been a problem for a while now, ever since the introduction of "extension hardening" in Office apps.  Basically if you're labelling content as Excel-format, it needs to actually *be* in Excel format.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not save in xls or xlsx file format. It saves an html file with xls or xlsx extension. HTML is a text file format and Excel file formats are binary formats. When the HTML file is open, MS Excel recognizes the inconsistency and raise a warning.

If you want to save real XLSX files, you must use an Excel library like [Open XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/) or [EasyXLS](https://www.easyxls.com).